# select row content on datagridview by hitting "enter" key in vb.net ,

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, enter

i have created a datagridview and some textboxes for that 
i want if a person hits enter in the selected ro the corresponding value should be filled in the textboxes of the form .

my current code provides me but it in cellclick event but i need this in press enter key event .

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow
        row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        iname.Text = row.Cells("Name").Value.ToString
        icode.Text = row.Cells("Item code").Value.ToString
        irate.Text = row.Cells("Rate").Value.ToString
        icomnt.Text = row.Cells("Comment").Value.ToString

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The `DGV` does have `KeyDown`, `KeyUp`, and `KeyPress` events. Did you try these?

Comment: i tried but not getting solution .

Comment: How about show the code, maybe there is something not right we could look at.

Comment: If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter And DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            e.Handled = True
            e.SuppressKeyPress = True

            Dim row As DataGridViewRow
            row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
            iname.Text = row.Cells("Name").Value.ToString

Comment: It's not clear what's not working with your code.  Put your code from your comment into your question by clicking on the edit link by the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyPress

```
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index - 1).Cells(0)
        txtno.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).Value
        
    End If
   
End Sub
```